# BreezeJS/Query - Predicate on expanded field issue

Tags: breeze

```
var p1 = breeze.Predicate.create("Status", "==", 3);
var p2 = breeze.Predicate.create("Client/Status", "==", 1);
var p = breeze.Predicate.and([p1, p2]);
```

In the above code, the final predicate p gets converted as:

```
(Status eq 3) and (Client/Status eq '1')
```

when it is viewed in Fiddler/Web inspector xhr view.

Why is the integer number 1 is considered as string ('1') when a predicate is created on an expanded entity's field ("Client/Status", see predicate p2). This causes the http request to fail as a bad request.

The same kind of predicate is constructed correctly on a first level field ("Status", see predicate p1).

Note: This request works fine when I go to Fiddler, remove the single quotes around the value 1 and execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you need to use a dots '.' to separate the parts of the path instead of a '/'. i.e.

```
var p2 = breeze.Predicate.create("Client.Status", "==", 1);
```

The reason that you are seeing 'Client/Status' interpreted as a string is that breeze defaults values to strings when it is unable to determine the actual datatype of the field.  It determines the datatype by navigating the path and determining the datatype of each segment via metadata.

Hope this helps.